# Quickbooks error message: something has been deleted

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

When we sent some data to Quickbooks Online to sync up, the following error was returned. The values looked fine. How to further investigate this problem?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
  <Message>Something you're trying to use has been deleted. Check the fields with accounts, customers, items, vendors or employees.</Message>
  <ErrorCode>-20403</ErrorCode>
  <Cause>SERVER</Cause>
</FaultInfo>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bill xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
  <Header>
    <DocNumber>D968866A85B</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2014-05-18</TxnDate>
    <Note>April Home Based Expenses</Note>
    <VendorId>2014</VendorId>
    <TotalAmt>-150.00</TotalAmt>
  </Header>
  <Line>
    <Desc>Internet/Online Fees:Home Based Expenses:Troy Cable</Desc>
    <Amount>50.00</Amount>
    <ClassId idDomain="QBO">3000000000000299133</ClassId>
    <AccountId idDomain="QBO">51</AccountId>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Desc>Mobile/Cellular Phone:Home Based Expenses:Verizon Wireless</Desc>
    <Amount>100.00</Amount>
    <ClassId idDomain="QBO">3000000000000299133</ClassId>
    <AccountId idDomain="QBO">51</AccountId>
  </Line>
</Bill>
```

I searched online and found that could be a bad bank account. But no bank account is in this XML string we sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your vendor, 2014, or account, 51, reference has been deleted. Check each manually on QBO or with an API call.

Comment: Yes you are right. The value should be 588, not 51. Somehow the ID value changed for this account. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason that the account ID value will change in Intuit? This has happened to a few clients. The account name remains the same, while the Id value changed.